# Flex child change when parent wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

firstly sorry for my English,

I ask me if we can change the style of a last child in flex div when this one goes to the line (wrap).

What I want precisely is to modify the last child (.flexChild in demo) to change the justify-content at space-around or to add padding when the user is on mobile or he resize the window

(without mediaqueries)

[DEMO Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o8tj2pg7/14/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flexChild {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Testtestesttest
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    testtesttestt
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    testesttestest
  </div>
  <div class="child flexChild">
    <div class="left">
      <button>1</button>
      <button>2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <button>3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use the selector `:last-child` and set the `space-around` using a media-querie

Comment: I know, but I'm asking if there's a way to do it without media queries

Comment: Using only css you cant check the resize without media queries